# ts-node not reading typeRoots

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, ts-node

I have the `typeRoots` set up like this:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "src/types/*.d.ts"
]
```

And `express.d.ts` inside that folder:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user?: any;
    }
  }
}
```

My editor (WebStorm) picks this up and does not show `req.user` as an error, but when I run this under `ts-node`, it says the property `user` does not exist.